# onclick get index of image in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

onclick get image index in for loop in javascript not jquery, the main problem here is that i can't access any global variable in function

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/2.jpg" width="350" height="250">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" width="350" height="250">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" width="350" height="250">
        <img src="images/5.jpg" width="350" height="250">
        <img src="images/6.jpg" width="350" height="250">
        <img src="images/7.jpg" width="350" height="250">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
    /*external javascript file code */
    var img = document.images;
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<img.length;i++){
        img[i].src = "images/1.jpg";
    //after changing image src i just want to show index of clicked image
        img[i].onclick = function(){
            alert("i m img "+ i);
            console.log(i);
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the index in your own html attribute like `index-data` using `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`:

```js
var img = document.images;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].src = "images/1.jpg";
  img[i].setAttribute("index-data", i);
  //after changing image src i just want to show index of clicked image
  img[i].onclick = function() {
    var index = this.getAttribute("index-data");
    console.log(index);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="images/2.jpg" width="350" height="250">
<img src="images/3.jpg" width="350" height="250">
<img src="images/4.jpg" width="350" height="250">
<img src="images/5.jpg" width="350" height="250">
<img src="images/6.jpg" width="350" height="250">
<img src="images/7.jpg" width="350" height="250">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical closure problem inside a loop. 
The simple solution to this problem is to wrap the code block which has 
indefinite execution, inside a IIFE block.
read about it here :  [Javascript closures](http://markheath.net/post/javascript-closure-loop-gotcha)

```
 for(i=0;i<img.length;i++){
        img[i].src = "images/1.jpg";
       (function(index){

         img[index].onclick = function(){
            alert("i m img "+ index);
            console.log(index);
        }

        })(i)


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute **[`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)** to store the current index.

```js
var img = document.images;
var i;
var images = ['https://www.hrexaminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2016-10-11-hrexaminer-stackoverflow-6-xxl-sq-250px.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2FO1.jpg?s=48&g=1']
for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].src = images[i];
  img[i].dataset.index = i;
  img[i].onclick = function() {
    var index = this.dataset.index;
    console.log(index);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="" width="100" height="100">
<img src="" width="100" height="100">
```